# QGIS- Items printing to the atlas that don't exist

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have an atlas I made with 13 or so pages, when I print it to PDF items are showing up on the pages that don't actually exist in QGIS, I can use a PDF editor to delete them but it is annoying.

The items appear to be text boxes, I have scrolled through the items list so many times and the text boxes don't exist

Anyone else have a similar issue?

Comment: Could you show more context, like screenshots of your project showing layers panel and print layout.

Comment: If you exported a geospatial pdf with layers in Adobe you could look in the pdf for labels that you can turn off or on to find a problem  one.  If that doesn't find something then do the same with layers to see if the boxes are associated with a layer.  If you find one check its labeling properties and its geometry.  If you don't have layers you could turn layers on or off prior to export to see if anyone being off fixes things.